# Can a normal Class use Response.Redirect to a Uri?

Tags: redirect

I have the below code but hitting an error saying "**Response is not available in this context.**" What is wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
    }

    public void MoveToSite(string url)
    {
        System.Web.UI.Page Resp = new Page();
        Resp.Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Response object of a Page is an instance which represents the current HTTP response. It is passed to a page when it is created by ASP.NET. If you create a new page, it does magically get the Request property, somebody has to set it.

You can access the current request like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(...)
```

But it may be better to pass the Response object to your Class1 when constructing a new object of type Class1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the Response object via `HttpContext.Current.Response`